# How can I combine a time column and and Day of month column to make a date-time

Tags: python, pandas

I have a time column that is in `string format("10:27:30 PM")` and a column that shows the day of the month as type int. I want to clean my data for my machine learning model. I changed the time column into a date-time data type by using  `df['Time'] = df['Time'].astype('datetime64')`. The returned column has values that have today's date and the time in 24hr format (2020-08-28 10:27:30). I also changed the 'Day of the month' column using

```
df[['Pickup - Day of Month']] = pd.to_datetime(df['Pickup - Day of Month'], format="%d")
```

and it changed to '1900-01-31', 31 is the day of the month. I also tried splitting the day, hour, minutes, seconds into different columns and the return type are all type int columns. How can I clean data like this in pandas for my machine learning models?  any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to SO.. instead of just dumping some text you can show some sample data, code & expected output would have a better change of getting attention [`see here`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/4985099).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `origin` parameter of [pd.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html). You can specify any date you want as the first date instead of `1900-01-01`.

And then add your time to this date column with [pd.to_timedelta](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html)

```
df['DateTimeColumn'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Pickup - Day of Month'], origin=pd.Timestamp('2020-08-01') \
    + pd.to_timedelta(df.Time)
```